# Looping through WMS Layers on a map

Tags: leaflet, javascript, layers

I am drafting an application with Leaflet. Basically, I need to add several WMS layers and then cycle through them with a timed loop. This is the code (still a draft, I don't tested it) but I am missing a function for "`showLayer(i)`".

```
  var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
          osm = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, {maxZoom: 18}),
          mymap = new L.Map('map', {layers: [osm], center: new L.LatLng(41.69906, 12.39258), zoom: 5, maxZoom:8});

    var optionsArray =['opt1', 'opt2', ...];
    var layer = new Array(myoptionsArray.length);

    for (i = 0; i < myoptionsArray.length; i++) {
        l = L.tileLayer.wms(url, {optionsArray[i]});
        layer.push = l
        l.addTo(mymap);
        }


    function myLoop(){
      ...count on i....
      showLayer(i);
      timerID = setTimeout(myLoop, 500);
    }

    myLoop();

    function showLayer(i){
        ?????
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All layers added to the map are shown in the order they were added, each one covering the previous one. If only one layer should be shown at one time there is no need to add them all at once at the beginning. Just add the new one and remove previous one.

Code could look like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < myoptionsArray.length; i++) {
    l = L.tileLayer.wms(url, {optionsArray[i]});
    layer.push = l
    }

function myLoop(){
  ...count on i....
  showLayer(i);
  timerID = setTimeout(myLoop, 500);
}

var currLayer = -1;

myLoop();

function showLayer(i){
   if (currLayer >= 0) {
     mymap.removeLayer(layer[currLayer])
   }
  mymap.addLayer(layer[i]);
  currLayer = i;
}
```

To prevent flickering when new layer is added (loaded), adding and removing layers and zIndexing can be combined. First load new layer behind the current one and after some timeout (to be sure that layer is loaded) put new layer on top and remove old layer:

```
for (i = 0; i < myoptionsArray.length; i++) {
    l = L.tileLayer.wms(url, {optionsArray[i]});
    layer.push = l
    }

function myLoop(){
  ...count on i....
  showLayer(i);
  timerID = setTimeout(myLoop, 100);
}

var currLayer = -1;

myLoop();

function showLayer(i){
  layer[i].setZIndex(5);
  mymap.addLayer(layer[i]);
  setTimeout(showIt, 400, i);
}

function showIt(i) {
  layer[i].setZIndex(10);
  if (currLayer >= 0) {
    mymap.removeLayer(layer[currLayer]);
  }
  currLayer = i;
}
```

Comment: I already did that, but the trick to add & remove generates a flickering on the display screen while the layers are looping. I had to load them all and then use bringToFront.

Comment: I understand from this that you resolved your problem with bringToFront method.

Comment: Yes, it is working, but I am not happy as I am loading all the layers and then select them with that method. I'm afraid it is loading too much the browser. I'd rather use the removeLayer method you suggested, but the flickering was very bad. Thank you anyway.

Comment: To prevent flickering, methods can be combined: adding, removing and zIndexing layers. See modified answer.

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work?

Comment: Yes, thank you. Not exactly your code, but you pointed me to the right direction.